# Final answer rendering is different in the editor preview

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237105/const-in-javascript-when-to-use-it-and-is-it-necessary) and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32992437). Since the answer can be edited to look like a list, I tried to edit it, but to my surprise the formatting in the editor preview is different and looks correct.

Here's the images of said difference:

- On the main site:

> [image: Answer]

- In the editor preview:

> [image: Editor preview]

And here's the source of the problematic answer:

```
It provides:
1) a constant reference, eg const x = [] - the array can be modified, but x can't point to another array; and
2) block scoping.
const and let will together replace var in ecma6/2015
See discussion at https://strongloop.com/strongblog/es6-variable-declarations/
```

---

Pasting the answer source here to see if it differs also in meta:

It provides:

1. a constant reference, eg const x = [] - the array can be modified, but x can't point to another array; and
2. block scoping.
   const and let will together replace var in ecma6/2015
   See discussion at https://strongloop.com/strongblog/es6-variable-declarations/

> [image: Meta test]

---

Ninja **edit**: It looks correct as expected, and I might try answering here to see if it only affects answers.

Another **edit**: Answer test. It looks like it renders correctly(?).

> [image: Testing here in meta]

Comment: ... Last edit is from 2015? I guess the script that did update all posts when [passing to CommonMark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398481/3702797) missed that post, and that a simple edit now would make the updated server-side code re-render this correctly. Not sure if it should be left as is for devs to check why the script missed it though.

Comment: I see thanks, will submit an edit now for that particular answer.

Comment: @Kaiido IIRC the script purposefully missed ones that it wasn't certain wouldn't result in it breaking something, the intention being for them to be picked up as and when they were found and needed edited. Edit with src [*"Again, if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Overflow is migrating to CommonMark on Saturday, June 20, 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398481/stack-overflow-is-migrating-to-commonmark-on-saturday-june-20-2020)

Comment: See [this answer in “We’re switching to CommonMark”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348753/289905).