# Markdown headers with hash are not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

While reading [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26461698/3982001) I found a dead link, and I've just replaced it with the correct one. Now the link is fine, but somehow I've broken header formatting, although I didn't change anything apart from the link. Before my edit the headers were rendered correctly.

The syntax that is used is the "triple-hash" one, but there's no space between `###` and the following word:

```
###On the console 
You should use the flag `--gtest_filter`, like
```

This is rendered like this:

> ###On the console
> You should use the flag `--gtest_filter`, like

whereas adding a space:

```
### On the console 
You should use the flag `--gtest_filter`, like
```

solves the problem:

> #### On the console
>
> You should use the flag `--gtest_filter`, like

Is the Markdown-to-HTML conversion done only when a post is saved, and did the renderer change since the last edit? That would explain it, I guess. But I thought Markdown is rendered on the fly, and in that case I don't understand what's going on.

But in any case, sometimes the renderer is indeed changed, but I think in that case a script is run to update all the posts that would be affected. Was this one missed?

For the moment I don't want to modify that answer, in case anyone wants to see the bug. I'll take care of it after this has been solved.

Comment: See: "[We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/271271)" and "[Stack Overflow is migrating to CommonMark on Saturday, June 20, 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398481/3773011)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the Markdown-to-HTML conversion done only when a post is saved, and did the renderer change since the last edit?

Yes, and yes.

---

> But I thought Markdown is rendered on the fly, and in that case I don't understand what's going on.

Quoting from [Why use server side markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41687/684990): *"And then what do you do when people have javascript disabled?"*

If I recall correctly, the client side renderer is only used for the preview when editing a post. Hence why differences between preview and final render [should be reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/684990):

> The preview will show you what your post will look like and once you save your post, it should appear just as you saw it in the preview. ***If you notice any differences between preview and saved post, please let us know!***

---

> But in any case, sometimes the renderer is indeed changed, but I think in that case a script is run to update all the posts that would be affected. Was this one missed?

It wasn't possible to update all posts and in some cases, yes, posts were missed as it would have changed the way that the post was rendered, from [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>:

> We avoid breaking existing posts by erring on the side of safety. ***If a post looks different using the new renderer (and if it’s just one whitespace off) we won’t automatically re-render the post*** and put it up for investigation first. This way we can be sure that all changes are safe.
>
> ...
>
> Things might get funky when you're editing a post that renders differently with the new CommonMark renderer. ***Again, if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration. This way, all posts continue to look the same when being viewed. However, once someone comes in and edits it, it will be rendered using the new CommonMark renderer and this might cause the post to look slightly different than what we had before.*** This will only be a small fraction of all of our posts, and of that small fraction a smaller fraction will actually be edited moving forward. However, it's important to keep in mind that editing old posts has a slight chance that you run into differences between our old and our new markdown renderers.