# I cannot edit the snippet after posting an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

This is really annoying, but I no more see the edit snippet link to edit the code of my answer.

Is it probably related to [the CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)?

<strike>It's happening for me here: [How to make the image "normal" in a skewed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62493321/8620333) (for both the question and my answer)</strike> (the fix is taking too long, so I already edited the answer to avoid the issue. Check the below answers to reproduce the issue).

> [image]

Comment: I can confirm this is happening. I, also, don't see the "edit the above snippet" button when editing the question or existing answer on the linked page.  I *do* see the button when editing a new answer on that page if I use the "Copy snippet to answer" button in the question. I also see that button when editing other posts on other pages.

Comment: When did the Expand snippet link show up?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I guess since always (or at least too long). I don't remember when it wasn't there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for being late about this, after migrating all sites to CommonMark I took a few days off to refresh so I only got to investigate this issue today.

I found the source of the issue. We're replacing tabs with spaces before processing Markdown to HTML. After switching to the new CommonMark renderer, I put the tab-to-spaces replacement into the processing chain too late so that processing snippets was done before tabs were stripped.

To reiterate: The fact that tabs are being replaced with spaces is intentional.

I just rolled out a fix for this issue and the bug should disappear. Thanks for getting this on my radar!

Comment: Thanks for this fix. Regarding "The fact that tabs are being replaced with spaces is intentional." does this mean that the fact that it wasn't previously as can be seen in [this question's snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380716/) (feb. '19) *was* a bug? And while you're in this area, do you think updating the live preview so it does the replacement directly there would be doable? Kind of frustrating to have three different renderings of the same input (snippet, live-preview, posted all differ).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the `\t` tab character is freaking out the code.

Here is a snippet with a `\t` tab where the link doesn't appear when editing.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Replacing this `\t` character with spaces would make the link appear.
Also, adding another snippet without a `\t` character would make the link appear under the first snippet too.

Comment: Should be noted that the `\t` character is replaced by 4 spaces in the *rendered* markup, which is arguably quite bad for code blocks.

Comment: sounds like the new CommonMark has to do with this. So I have to get rid of ALL the `\t` inside the snippet? a bit tedious job ...

Comment: *["No more tabs!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=9m37s)*

Answer (score 5):

Here is the same snippet as in my [previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398557/3702797), with the `\t` tab character replaced with 4 spaces where the link appears:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```