# Don't rerender the post when the "show preview" has been toggled off

Tags: feature-request, editor

#### The problem:

I often have to edit some of my answers or others' with my quite low-end mobile-phone and on long posts with a few Stack-Snippets, re-rendering the preview can take seconds.
This re-rendering apparently happens every time a new character is entered in the textarea, which means I have to wait seconds between each characters, not a great UX.

There is a "show preview" / "hide preview" button that appears in *edit mode* between the textarea and the preview container. This toggle allows, well, to show and hide this preview.
So of course I thought that would solve my problem, until I realize that all it does is to set a `display: none` on the container. All the js rendering routine, syntax highlighting, snippet's empty iframes document's generation etc. is still done, apparently at every keystroke...
All that is saved from this toggle is the final painting.

#### The proposal:

**Disable the javascript renderer when this toggle is set to hide the preview.**

Comment: related : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373443/8620333 (not sure if you can use the userscript on mobile)